# Проблема с созданием репозитория именно через гит хаб

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push

После добавления изменений в файл Readme.md коммиты не сохраняются , конфиг успешно пройден вс код соединён с гит хабом , при локальной работе все работает отлично , но при создании репозитория через гит хаб не получается добавить коммит , после ввода команды git commit -m "сообщение" , выдает 1 file changed , 0 insertions , 0 delections (-), в следствии чего при попытке запушить выдаёт ошибку так как нет коммитов , но команда git log --oneline , выдает как будто коммит имеется , но без цифры в начале сразу с буквы начинается, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Прежде чем коммитить, надо файлы добавить в индекс...

Comment: *"выдает как будто коммит имеется , но без цифры в начале сразу с буквы начинается, "* --- какие цифры какие буквы?